# cakephp login page doesn't go anywhere

Tags: cakephp, authentication, redirect, cakephp-2.0

I have tried to set up a login page, but when I try to log in, even with a wrong username/password, cake redirects to the login page (the logout function redirects correctly).   Even if I plug in the wrong info, I get no error flashes at all, I don't get it.  Here is my controller code:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
public $name='Users';
public $layout='pagelayout';
public $uses=array('User');



public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout', 'overview');
}

public function login() {
$this->set('title', 'Log in to your Gulf Shores 4 Less account');
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
    }
}
```

}

and here is my model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class User extends AppModel {
public $name='User';
public $hasMany=array('Unit', 'Complex', 'Coupon', 'Location', 'Image', 'Charter', 'Course', 'Nightclub', 'Store');

public function beforeSave() {
if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
}
return true;
}
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A username is required'
        )
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A password is required'
        )
    ),
    'role' => array(
        'valid' => array(
            'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'advertiser')),
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
            'allowEmpty' => false
        )
    )
  );
}

?>
```

Here is the code from AppController:

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
 public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'overview'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index')
    )
);


function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('login','index', 'view', 'condos', 'houses', 'hotels_and_motels', 'print_all_coupons', 'print_coupon', 'search', 'golf', 'charters', 'events', 'nightlife', 'shopping', 'visitors_info', 'contact_us');
}
}
?>
```

and here is the view code:

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login'));?>
</div>
```

As you can see, I pretty much copy and pasted what was in the Cakephp-2.0 manual for this.  The only difference between my db table and the manual's is that my password is stored as an MD5 hash in my users table.  i can't figure out where this has derailed.

Comment: **Update** I changed my login() function that now gives me an error message when the login info is incorrect.  I think the problem now is that because my passwords are stored in the db with MD5 hashes, it isn't checking for the correct password.  How do i tell Cake to use an MD5 hash checker?

Comment: **Update** Again.  I read that the default hash in cake is sha1 so I changed one of my passwords to a sha1 hash and still, I stay on the login page (tho it does still tell me incorrect username/password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your passwords are stored using the Auth component hash. AFAIK, there is no support for 'plain' md5 passwords. The hashes Cake generates are more complex than md5.

See the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords) for info on how to hash your passwords. If you are migrating from an app that used md5 hashing, you'll have to reset all the passwords to something random for all your users.

Comment: Ok, I had already stuck storing into my model, but I tested by creating a user (and it worked correctly, redirecting to the right page).  Problem is that my already created users have the wrong hash.  I can definitely change them as this is all still in testing mode, I just need to know exactly what cake is using so i can find the right online hash generator.

Comment: There is an SHA1 function in phpmyadmin that you can use to convert.  Is this what you have been doing?

Comment: Well, NO, I hadn't.  I didn't know I could do that!  This is literally my first day at trying to make a login page and uses hashes and everything.  Anyways, I went into my db and wrote in a password on an already created user, put SHA1 as a function on it in phpmyadmin, and it *sigh* did not work.  Still giving me the 'incorrect username/password' error and not redirecting.

Comment: @HeatherWalters There is no "right online hash generator" other than Cake's own hashing methods. The hashing method uses unique keys from your application config file, so it is extra secure. NO online tool will be able to generate hashes that will work for your cake app other than the `AuthComponent::password` method (and only if it's called from within your own app). You can also call this function with 'raw' text like: `AuthComponent::password('secret');` and should return the proper hash you will need in your db.

Comment: That was what I needed, thank you!  I'm having another problem with my function not passing the user id into the view, will post in another thread.  Marking your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following codes on your AppController.php file

**AppController.php**

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'User'),
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        );
        $this->Auth->authorize =false;
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'media', 'action' => 'index/');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = '/logout';
        $this->Auth->loginError = 'Invalid e-mail / password combination. Please try again';
```