# Strange behavior of CakePHP 2.2 app on webserver

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have developed a simple Cake application and after finishing coding of it, I uploaded it to [my web server](http://server.3p3r.com) and now it has several problems (It works like a charm on localhost):

- `setFlash` messages doesn't work (I'm using Sessions in database and there are records of some sessions in `cake_sessions`)
- After a successful login, it'll redirect me to the login page again.
- Sometimes cache files just disappear! (My `tmp` folder is writeable)

Actually no actions is allowed before logging in but you should see a `You are not authorized to access that location.` flash message on top of login page but it just doesn't appear however if you login with a bad username/password it'll show a message(`wth?`)

Login and Logout methods of UsersController:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}

public function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Last 100 queries executed (from logs):

```
SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `srv`.`cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '7orjo8clp192qeie55k6pqro26' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Can you please post the login component and the login action from the users controller?

Comment: @user1104854 Actually since this app is a private app and shouldn't have any extra accounts, I didn't write anything more on Users Model. everything is handled in controller. methods added.

Comment: I would first confirm that if the problem is indeed due to sessions. Try using php configured session once and see if the problem persists. Also, check the apache error log to see if there are other issues on the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like sessions are broken on your webserver. Check your system clock - if it differs by more than a few minutes your sessions will expire very quickly, if not immediately

Comment: I've noticed that my server is ~7 hours behind the world's clock. I think that is the problem. I'll report back any success or failure. But something is so odd to me and that is, everything works great in Gecko based browsers! like Seamonkey and Firefox!!

Comment: It's a fairly common problem on virtualized servers, because time is generally tracked by counting CPU cycles. When cycles are sliced up across virtualized servers, it falls behind. Run ntpdate on your server to correct the time, and ask the server administrator to keep it up to date for you.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Actually I have a XEN based vps and since its back-end is XEN, it doesn't have `hwclock` and my server's time was set to be synced by a non existent `hwclock` service.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the component set up for the login in your users model. It should be something like

```
 public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'desired_controller', 'action' => 'desired_action'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'desired_controller', 'action' => 'display', 'home')
    )
);
```

Also check to make sure you have the beforeFilter set up correctly

```
//UsersController

  public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout', 'other_actions');
}
```

**edit**

this seems very similar to what you're describing [cakephp login page doesn't go anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266833/cakephp-login-page-doesnt-go-anywhere)

This also may be worth checking out considering the strange behavior

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/c96e364cbb6ec8dd72dd220836a07ed104d2d50a . It fixes the incorrect expiry of sessions

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already have those on top of my AppController. I have `loginRedirect` filled and `logoutRedirect` empty since Cake fills `logoutRedirect` by default to the login page.

Comment: I have them too. I think something is wrong with Cake's core itself.

Comment: Do you have the last query being displayed? It should have been enabled by default. If not, open up default.ctp and add this towards the bottom. <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?> Try to log in and post the query results

Comment: added them, it seems that it doesn't even reach the Auth component!

Comment: Try this patch. It fixes the incorrect expiry of sessions which appears to be happening to you. https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/c96e364cbb6ec8dd72dd220836a07ed104d2d50a

Comment: I already have that patch in my `DatabaseSession.php`. thanks for your answers but I've noticed that my server is ~7 hours behind the world's clock. I think that is the problem.